# Inference of a function f(x,y) where inputs have different dimensionality

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, regression

I am interested in inferring the value of a high dimensional unknown function f which accepts two inputs, let's say x and y, with very different dimensionality (for example x could be a vector with hundreds of entries, whereas y could be a vector with less than 10 components). Of course, my training dataset is composed of many measurements of x, y and the corresponding values of the function. By the way, x, y, and f take real values, so this is a regression problem.

My first idea to tackle this problem would be to train a multi-layer perception in which the input of the network is a vector where x and y are stacked over each other and the output is the corresponding value of the function f. However, such an approach seems sub-optimal to me, because intuitively the low dimensional input (i.e. y) would end up playing a negligible role in the approximation of f. In other words, I already know from the nature of my problem that every single value in y is more relevant to the approximation of f than any of the many components in x. My question then is: **what would be a better algorithm to tackle this regression problem with multiple inputs with different dimensionality?**

I apologize if the question is trivial, but I am not a data scientist and I could not find any good answers online.